# Use auth token to query a private NPM registry for a given package version, but without filesystem access?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, readonly, npm-registry

The purpose of this effort is to be able to test whether a package version exists in a private registry, **without having to touch the filesystem / config files**.  For packages in public registries this is perfectly straightforward: `npm view lpad@2.0.1` produces some information about that published version, but (as of this writing) `npm view lpad@201.0.0` does not have any information or output.  I'm using this to infer the existence of packages.

I can also pass a private registry URL to `npm view <packagename>`, as in `npm view <packagename> --registry https://private.registry/path/`.  This seems to hit the private registry even though it isn't explicitly mentioned in [the `npm-view` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) (but it's described in [the `npm-search` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search.html), so I take this to mean it's a documented API feature).

To be able to talk to private registries at all, I can use an authentication token in the query according to [these npm instructions for doing it in a CI/CD workflow](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow): put it into the `.npmrc` file like this:

```
//your_registry/:_authToken 12345
```

Or more securely, `//your_registry/:_authToken $TOKEN` and set the `TOKEN` environment variable to `12345` elsewhere.

What I *can't* figure out how to do is use `npm view` against a private `npm` registry, **without writing to the `.npmrc` file**.

I plan to be running several queries in parallel from the same machine, so to avoid race conditions in the `.npmrc` file, I'd rather pass the authentication directly in each command.  I assume that with an auth token, this is just a simple `curl` command but I haven't had much luck finding information on how the NPM API works.  (The [`npm-registry-client`](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client) doesn't appear to do anything related to view/find; it has `access` which *sets* an access level).

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?  Where can I find a guide on the request format for view and/or search functions of an NPM registry?  What is the `curl` command that includes sending the auth token, package name, and version and receives some indication of whether it exists?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/user/authentication.md

```sh
#!/bin/sh
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' https://your_registry/$PACKAGE/$VERSION
```

If the package does not exist, it will return `{}`.  If it does, you'll get the package information.